# Queue with Thread hangs when worker crashes

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I am using Python Queue with Thread.  I noticed when a worker crashes, the script hangs and doesn't let me terminate.  The following is an example:

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

num_worker_threads = 2

def worker():
        while True:
                item = q.get() 
                1/item
                q.task_done()
q = Queue()
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
        t = Thread(target=worker)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

q.put(0)
q.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by wrapping the job in an exception.  I would have thought that when a worker crashes, the script would exit. This is not the case.  It looks like q.task_done() never gets called so it hangs on q.join().

Solution:

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

num_worker_threads = 2

def worker():
        while True:
                item = q.get()
                try:
                        1/item
                except Exception as e:
                        print e
                finally:
                        q.task_done()
q = Queue()
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
        t = Thread(target=worker)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

q.put(0)
q.join()
```

Added suggestion by rsy.

Answer (score 1):

An even cleaner approach would be to have task_done() in the finally block instead.

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

num_worker_threads = 2

def worker():
        while True:
                item = q.get()
                try:
                        1/item
                except Exception as e:
                        print e
                finally: 
                      q.task_done()
q = Queue()
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
        t = Thread(target=worker)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

q.put(0)
q.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `while True` which is continuously trying to get elements from the `Queue` by using `q.get()` in your thread, but there may not be any items in the queue. Which will throw an `Empty` exception since there's nothing in the queue to actually get.

Your loop should be `while not q.empty():` or you should be catching the `Queue.Empty` exception.

Comment: If the worker threads are daemon they will terminate when the main thread terminates.  The main thread only terminated when all tasks involving the queue were complete.  It was hanging because the task never completed because it hit an exception.